# iPhone in-app purchase screen shot

Tags: iphone, screenshot, in-app-purchase

When posting an in-app purchase with Apple they ask for a screenshot to be included before going to review.

What kind of screenshots do they want?

My in-app purchase unlocks some of the lite version, I'm not sure what Apple wants to see here.

Comment: Apple lists the dimensions of screenshots for In-App purchases for all device types here and the list what they expect it to show: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html I wish they would just stick it right on the screen where it is required so you don't have to go digging all over the place to find it, grrrrrrrrrrr.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have provided an image of the dialog I present to the user when I ask them to confirm the purchase...and it was accepted

Comment: Do you remember how long it to for them to review it?

Comment: @ByronCoetsee, about a week, but this is highly variable depending on the reviewers' load. For example, when a new version of the iOS is out, or a new device is out (e.g. the watch), the reviewers get slammed so it can take longer

Comment: I want to know how can i post screenshot of in-app purchase dialog if the app is in review state. I can only test In-App Purchases in sandbox environment with test iTunes account? Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

I provided a screenshot of the **Confirm Your In-App Purchase** dialog that StoreKit presents when purchasing each product, and everything was approved by Apple the first time. I didn't show screenshots of how the app changed before & after the IAP, so it doesn't seem as though this is required.

Here's one of the screenshots I used:

[image: Example screenshot for In App Purchase]

Comment: Do you remember how long it to for them to review it?

Comment: @ByronCoetsee I don't remember, but the review time always varies. You can get a rough idea by looking at a site like: http://appreviewtimes.com

Answer (score 27):

Quoted directly from Apple's In App Purchase Guidelines

> For review purposes only. Your In App Purchase screenshot will not display on the App Store or on the iPhone device store. Once you have tested your In App Purchase and are ready to sign off, upload a screenshot of your In App Purchase in this section. The screenshot should be a clear picture of your In App Purchase in action and must be 320 x 480, 480 x 320, 320 x 460, or 480 x 300 pixels.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

The correct size is now 640 x 920. The other sizes are no longer accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'm aware of this, and in my case my app looks virtually identical to the screenshots included in the app profile. The purchase unlocks more of the same. I'm not sure what to offer Apple here.

Comment: I think from what the quote says, you should supply the screenshot on how you do the purchase in your app (probably the storefront would be a good one) and must be one of the following sizes, 320 x 480, 480 x 320, 320 x 460, or 480 x 300 pixels. If nothing much changed, i think you could supply a similar screenshot. It's just part of a process they do for those in app purchases that might be different to guide them in review. Don't worry.

Comment: use 640x920 (please change the answer)

Comment: 640x920 (close to 2:3 aspect ratio last seen on iPhone 4s) works, 640x1136 (9:16 like iPhone SE) as well. Which size works for more recent iPhones with a notch and a 9:19.5 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 18):

The screenshot has now (February 9 2017) to be at least 640x920.

Comment: Right answar !!

Comment: To the top!! You save my day!

Comment: please up vote this and down vote the older answer because it is out of date.

Answer (score 6):

According to Apple:

> Screenshots requirements are outlined below: iOS requires at least 640
> x 920 pixels.

I'm working on this right now (end of July 2020) and only exact resolution of 640x920 uploads successfully. I tried higher resolutions and 640xH(H>920) without success.

Comment: In 2021, 640x920 (close to 2:3 aspect ratio last seen on iPhone 4s) works, 640x1136 (9:16 like iPhone SE) as well. Which size works for more recent iPhones with a notch and a 9:19.5 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3):

This screenshot should show situation when in-app purchase will be activated, in your case it can be screen of application without 'lite version' restriction (or directly after purchase).

Comment: Thank you for your post. The purchase unlocks more of the same. I'm not sure what to offer Apple here, over and above what's already included in the profile. Can I send a screenshot immediately after the purchase, if there isn't anything of interest to show?!

Comment: You can show for example screenshot of new main screen (with new buttons added, whatever else). Also, I think it would be enough of screenshot with 'Congratulation! Your application is now upgraded!'

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer such an old question, but this aspect hasn't been addressed: I have always felt the "screen shot of your in-app purchase" language was vague. I've learned in creating 400+ IAPs that it doesn't matter what the screen shot is, as long as it is the right size. I have submitted 10+ IAPs at the same time with the same screen shot that is just a random screen shot of my app that has nothing to do with the IAPs at all, and all have been approved.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the screen where you prompt the users for in-app purchase. Take screen shot and upload. It can be of real device or on simulator.

Comment: what if its an ipad? i am trying the same but the game is landscape.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the screenshot of the dialogue . no matter is it from sandbox or production.
Screenshot sample for you -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I uploaded this image with size 640 x 1136 and that success.  Mybe you can try this ..

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots requirements are outlined below:

A screenshot of the in-app purchase that represents the item being sold.

iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.

Here's more about it:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f

Answer (score -1):

***iOS 15 / Swift 5+ LATEST UPDATE***

> iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
>
> tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
>
> macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.

For More Details: [Visit this Link](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f)